# Checking if email address exists using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

After discussing this on SO Chat for hours, someone helped me get started and with a little additions by myself, the following JSFiddle was produced:

http://jsfiddle.net/aKENW/2/

I have created a test mysql database on another online server. I have also placed a validation file with the following php code in it:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...', '...', '...');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$emailInput = $_POST['signUpemail'];
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM people WHERE email=?');
$result->execute(array($emailInput));
$count = count($result->fetchAll());
if ($count > 0){
    echo 0;
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
?>
```

The above file is called `validation.php` and is placed on that same server. This file is accessed by the `url` parameter in the JSFiddle AJAX code.

I have added `action="google.com"` in the form declaration with the intent that the user is redirected to that url if the username entered is valid and the email entered is valid after being checked against my database.

The test email that already exists in the database is `test7@gmail.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I didn't make clear what the problem was in the original post. The problem is that the email is not validating at all. No matter what email address I put in the textbox, regardless of whether its in the database or not, it doesn't go through. The page is not being redirected to google.com. The only reason I added google.com is to make it obvious whether the form is actually working or not.

Comment: Who knows what's wrong, you're asking about two different problems in one post, and have only provided code for one.  Forget your client-side code for a minute.  Is your PHP script working?  Have you used your browser tools to make sure that the script is responding as expected?  Now client-side... why would you put your form action to google.com?  And finally, how can we help you with what you're doing wrong when you don't even say what is happening?

Comment: What's seems to be the question here, @DemCodeLines?  Does this code work?  Not work?  What's happening here?  You just posted code without telling us if it works or not, so I'm gonna assume it works :)

Comment: @Brad I edited and added some extra detail to the question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I edited and added some extra detail to the question.

Comment: note that if you implement this, any malicious person can fish for email addresses in your database

Comment: @dualed Thanks for letting me know that! May I ask why you think the script is insecure?

Comment: Not insecure necessarily, but one would only have to try typical mail address combinations like john.snow@thrones.com this is why password recovery pages should never tell you whether they actually found the address you entered

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code doesn't send any form parameters to your PHP script:

```
document.getElementById('signUpemail').onkeyup = function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://demcode.5gbfree.com/validate.php',
        success: function (data) {
            createError('Username is already registered');
        }
    });
}
```

Put [some data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) into your arguments to `$.ajax()` and see what happens.

Comment: after seeing the edit you made to your post: I think you're a bit confused about how forms and AJAX work together (hint: they don't).  Your form action is only invoked when you submit the form by clicking its submit button.  Calling $.ajax() has nothing to do with form actions.

Comment: @DemCodeLines: You need to send an object, not just the value.  `data: { signUpemail: $('signUpemail').val() }`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I added that, it made no difference though.

Comment: @DemCodeLines: Are you testing this in the jsFiddle, or on your own site?  You cannot post to that page via AJAX in the jsFiddle.  That's against the Same-Origin Policy.